# WCF Service (wsHttpBinding binding) behind F5 load balancer

Tags: wcf, https, f5

current setup:
- i have got a WCF service with wsHttpBding, see the service config below
- i have implemented a ServiceHostFactory to solve the problem of incorrect schema location and soap addresses, modifying them from machine name to the correct server hostname
- my test client (WCFStorm) i can generate a proxy, see all the methods and invoke them successfully.
- my dev environment (client-> HTTPS -> service) works perfectly.

problems:
- prod environment (client -> HTTPS -> F5 -> HTTP -> service)
- my service is behind F5 load balancer which offloads SSL
- my test client (WCFStorm) i can generate a proxy and see all the methods but when i invoke any of the methods i get a remote server not found 404 error

- my service config:


  `<services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="Service1Behavior"
      name="MyService">
      <endpoint name="secure" address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="custBinding" contract="IService"/>
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    </service>
  </services>
  <bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
      <binding name="custBinding">
        <security mode="Transport">
          <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
          <message clientCredentialType="None" negotiateServiceCredential="false"
            establishSecurityContext="false" />
        </security>
      </binding>
    </wsHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="Service1Behavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl="http://myserver/MyService.svc"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="6553600" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>`
- please note that all my schema locations and soap addresses on the wsdl are correct in prod, but i simply cannot invoke any methods.

please help.

Comment: Did you get this sorted? I'm experiencing the exact same problem in the production environment!

Comment: @IgorK: see my answer below http://stackoverflow.com/a/14388045/247184

Answer (score 4):

We have a similar situation and here's how we got it working.

in the service - we changed the binding to use `basicHttpBinding` and added a key that must be passed with every request.

in the client - we changed the http in the config to https and in the `basicHttpBindings` config changed the security mode to `Transport` with `clientCredentialType="None"`.

Hope this helps.

UPDATE: I found this article soon after and I updated the configuration and it worked. So now we are using wsHttpBinding instead of basicHttpBinding.
https://web.archive.org/web/20151215000000*/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/morgan/archive/2010/04/15/setting-up-wcf-with-a-load-balancer-using-ssl-in-the-middle.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your service config is that the security mode is `Transport`, where in reality it should be `None`. Because any calls to your service will be HTTP behind F5 load balancer, you can not use `Transport` security mode there (client -> HTTPS -> F5 -> HTTP -> service). However, when calling the service from your client, the client config will need to be `Transport` security mode and the endpoint address will need to have an `HTTPS` address.

```
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="custBinding">
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
        <message clientCredentialType="None" negotiateServiceCredential="false" establishSecurityContext="false" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
```

Comment: For this answer, does "endpoint" needing SSL means at the F5?  Or beyond the F5 and all the way to the real assigned server?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little late for you, but here is how we do it.  Once I have generated the proxy, I just change the http: in the config to https.  Now, if I have to sometimes call it with ssl, and othertimes without, I will copy the config section, and give the copy a different name, and then when you construct the client, you can pass in the config name, and it will pick up the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

We couldn't get this working through Layer 7 load balancing - there was various error messages returned from the service. Instead it's set up on Layer 4 load balancing with no issues.